# how to do cloudformation validation for templates in a directory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, aws-cloudformation, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have some templates in my gitlab repo that need to be validated before transfered to S3 bucket. How can I let my gitlab ci run the cloudformation for the whole templates directory instead of naming each template individually?

I was thinking of something like

```
for file in /templates/*.yml; do aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://$file > validation.log; done
```

Any ideas on how to do this in the gitlab ci?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this with find/exec command, also redirecting logs to file might be a bad idea since it's easier to see them in job output.

Using a shell runner (or docker runner) with `aws` tool installed you can have the following script block:

```
script:
  - find path_to_templates -type f -name "*.yml" -exec aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://{} \;
```

replace **path_to_templates** with your actual directory in repo. It will execute your command for every file ending with .yml in that directory.